# Complex number manipulation involving taking modulus

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-numbers

I'm trying to work through a problem which involves proving that a given ring is a euclidean ring but I'm a little rusty on manipulating complex numbers.

It is given that $w=\frac{-1+\sqrt{-3}}{2}$. Let $a$, $b$ be integers.

I am told that $|a+bw|^2=(a+bw)\cdot(a+b\bar{w})$ where $\bar{w}$ is the complex conjugate of $w$. I cant see why this is. Am i missing something very obvious or has the solution skipped a few steps? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Let $w$ be **any** complex number:$$w=x+iy$$$$\therefore\bar{w}=x-iy$$Then we have:$$|a+bw|^2=|a+bx+iby|^2=(a+bx)^2+b^2y^2\tag{1}$$We also see that:$$a+bw=a+bx+iby$$$$a+b\bar{w}=a+bx-iby$$$$\therefore (a+bw)(a+b\bar{w})=(a+bx+iby)(a+bx+iby)$$$$=((a+bx)+iby)((a+bx)-iby)$$$$=(a+bx)^2+b^2y^2\tag{2}$$Now compare (1) and (2) and you have your desired result.

Comment: mega awesome, cheers

Comment: You are more than welcome my friend :)

Answer (score 1):

Using $|z|^2 = z\bar{z}$
$$|a+bw|^2 = (a+bw)\overline{(a+bw)} $$
$$|a+bw|^2 = (a+bw){(\bar{a}+\bar{b}\bar{w})} $$
$a$ and $b$ are real, so $\bar{a} = a$ and $\bar{b} = b$
$$|a+bw|^2 = (a+bw)(a+ b\bar{w}) $$